# How to send an Ajax post to a Django form without JQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I'm currently sending posts with ajax to a django form, but I need to do this without JQuery.

Here's the working JQuery version.

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/platform/post-tracking/",
    type : "POST",
    async: true,
    data : {
        account : 229829623,
        width : pageWidth
    }
});
```

How would I send this post request without JQuery?
I've tried this

```
data = {
        account : 229829623,
        width : pageWidth
}
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', '/platform/post-tracking/', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
request.send(data);
```

But the form isn't valid.

Django Form:

```
class TrackingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TrackedSession
        fields = ('account', 'width')
```

Django Model:

```
class TrackedSession(models.Model):
    account = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Django View:

```
def TrackDataView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TrackingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print "Form is valid."
            temp = form.save(commit=False)

            session = TrackedSession()
            session.account = temp.account
            session.trackedIp = trackingip
            session.width = temp.width
            session.save()
            print("Session Created")
    else:
        print "Form isn't valid."
        print form.errors
    response_data = "Success"
    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(response_data),
        content_type="application/json"
        )
```

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#post

Comment: That is the code I'm using but it still isn't valid in my django form.

Comment: Can you post your Django handling code, and your html/template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `data` argument to `request.send()` needs to be a URL-encoded string. jQuery converts an object to a string, but if you don't use jQuery you have to do it yourself.

```
data = 'account=229829623&width=' + encodeURIComponent(pageWidth);
request.send(data);
```

Comment: This is what I needed, the form validates now. Thanks!